# Why does REGEXP_REPLACE concatenate with a previous result?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

This looks like strange behaviour, and I get the same on the MySQL command line as via db<>fiddle:

> ```
> create table t(foo varchar(255));
> ```

> ```
> insert into t (foo) values
> ('the quick brown fox'),
> ('jumped over the lazy dog');
> ```

> ```
> select * from t;
> ```
>
> ```
> | foo                      |
> | :----------------------- |
> | the quick brown fox      |
> | jumped over the lazy dog |
> ```

> ```
> select regexp_replace(foo, '[^a-z]+', '-') from t;
> ```
>
> ```
> | regexp_replace(foo, '[^a-z]+', '-')         |
> | :------------------------------------------ |
> | the-quick-brown-fox                         |
> | the-quick-brown-foxjumped-over-the-lazy-dog |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=87e216a3013a82252e72a70f2854e397)*

I'd expect to see:

> ```
> select REGEXP_REPLACE(foo, '[^a-z]+', '-') from t;
> ```
>
> ```
> | REGEXP_REPLACE(foo, '[^a-z]+', '-') |
> | :---------------------------------- |
> | the-quick-brown-fox                 |
> | jumped-over-the-lazy-dog            |
> ```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a MySQL bug?

Comment: `select @bar := REGEXP_REPLACE(foo, '[^a-z]+', '-') from t;` gives wrong output on `db<>fiddle` too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90803), fixed in `8.0.12`.

> REGEXP_RELACE() results from one result set row could carry forward to
>   the next row, resulting in accumulation of previous results in the
>   current row.

Comment: Thanks — it looks like 8.0.12 isn't released yet: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads. When it is I'll update dbfiddle and confirm it's fixed!

Comment: Or MariaDB 10.0 ?